# systemctl not running scripts under system-sleep

Tags: bash, systemd, suspend

`systemctl hybrid-sleep` or anything similar is, according to the manual, supposed to execute all scripts found in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` and after that continue it's own execution.
Instead it completely and utterly ignores every single script I put in there:

```
gnome-terminal -e "touch Documents/qwert"
while [ 1 ] 
do
    echo hi
done
```

^ this should go in an infinite loop after creating a file. I've also tried things like `touch /home/u/Documents/qwert` etc.

I'm  pretty puzzled actually. 
It might actually be caused by the fact that hybrid-sleep, hibernate, etc. all lead to a crash *before* complete execution, i.e. my laptop is unable to enter any kind of power saving mode and instead goes into a completely frozen state with a blank screen - however, it logs out before that and only crashes after a couple of seconds, so I assume the scripts should be executed just fine; after all those should be executed even before logging out.

Comment: gnome-terminal won't run from there as there is no X server for it to connect to (it's running as root, not as your logged in user).  gnome-terminal isn't needed and is overkill here anyway.  just run `touch /home/u/Documents/qwert` without `gnome-terminal -e`

Comment: also:  1. make sure the script is executable (with `chmod +x scriptname`).  2. maybe add `#! /bin/sh` as the first line of the script.

Comment: @cas Man... I feel kinda dumb now. Adding `#! /bin/sh` was all that was needed. I've never had to use that before because I was starting all my scripts from the terminal. 
Thank you.

Comment: OK, i'll turn my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` won't run from there as there is no X server for it to connect to (it's running as root, not as your logged in user). `gnome-terminal` isn't needed and is overkill here anyway. Just run `touch /home/u/Documents/qwert` without `gnome-terminal -e`

also:

1. Make sure the script is executable (with chmod +x scriptname).
2. Add `#! /bin/sh` or (`#! /bin/bash` if you use any bash-only features) as the **first** line of the script.